# How to remove discountcode from checkout and transactional emails?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, discount, code

I'm working with magento 1.9.3.4 and I wold like to remove the Discount code (e.g. COUPONCODE1) from showing on the checkout and transnational emails. Is this possible?

Is there a controller/model/block/template that i should check for this?
So far I only saw the discount amount being called and not the code itself. I'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the block that calls the discount text and removed it there.

This might not be the best solution, but this was what I needed.